# Any clue why my Alamofire request is not passing post params?

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

any clue why the following alamofire post request is not passing data to backend ? any help would be much appreciated. I tried changing the URL encoding as well but no luck.

```
    //call WS
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "user_id": user.userId!,
        "source" : tripSource!,
        "source_lat" : tripSourceLat!,
        "source_long" :  tripSourceLong!,
        "dest" : tripDestination!,
        "dest_lat": tripDestinationLat!,
        "dest_long": tripDestinationLong!
    ]

    //show loading dialog
    showActivityIndicator()
    Alamofire.request(AppConstant.USER_CREATE_ALERT, method: .post,     parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
        {
            response in ...
```

Comment: What you are getting in response ?

Comment: A simple JSON of this form:$response['status'] = "success";
        $response['message'] = "Saved Successfully..."; I dumped the request on backend and it seems the $_request is empty.

Comment: If you are getting success then no issue from your side , Tell your server team to debug !!